# populate ontology with existing RDF using jena

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl, ontology

I have ontology in OWL schema and also I have existing RDF (individuals ) , Can I use Jena to populate my ontology with this existing RDF ? actually my OWL schema has seven classes only . If we can use jena what is the codes or methods to do this , with my thanks.

Comment: You need to add more detail.  It doesn't mean to "populate an ontology"  Is there some logical connection between your RDF file and your OWL ontology?  Please show samples of the data, and the results that you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the Jena Manual. This is a good example of an embarrassingly documented use-case.

- [Reading/Writing RDF Using Jena](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/)
- [Jena Ontology API](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/)

```java
final InputStream inputStream = null; // TODO get this from your file
final String language = "RDF/XML";    // TODO set this whatever your file is in
final OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM);
model.read(inputStream, language);
```

Comment: this mean I can import existing RDF to populate my ontology

Answer (score 0):

Following http://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/

```
OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
m.read(<your ontology file>);

// or for each class
OntClass clazz = m.createClass( NS + "MyClass" ); 

// Then, your individuals
Individual ind0 = m.createIndividual( NS + "ind0", clazz );
```

Comment: when I have more then 700 individuals ,as example, and this individuals existing and I want to populate ontology within, so how to add individuals 'Individual ind0 = m.createIndividual( NS + "ind0", clazz );' I think this for each one?

Comment: If this data is already in RDF you can import it using m.read(...), this should add your data to the Jena model. Otherwise, yes, for each entity you should create an individual.